# How to place cuboids with a list of points?

Tags: graphics3d, fractals

I have a list of points found in a 3D Sierpinski triangle. How do I replace these points with Cuboids? The points come from a nested list

```
B := NestList[W, {{RandomReal[], RandomReal[], RandomReal[]}}, numits];
```

where W is a list of transformations upon the random points and numits is the number of iterations of those transformations. I haven't been able to pipe these points into some sort of iterated cuboid function. I'm fairly new to Mathematica so any help would be so nice.

Answer (score 1):

```
pts = RandomReal[10, {20, 3}];

Graphics3D[{{Red, PointSize[Large], Point[pts]}, Translate[Cuboid[], pts]}]
```

[image]

Notice the reference point for `Cuboid[]`, marked in red (a corner, not the centre, but you can adjust the parameters).